# Give big-$\mathcal{O}$ Number of addition and multiplication the algorithm in question uses

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Similar to a post I had here: [The time complexity of the binary search algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4011233/the-time-complexity-of-the-binary-search-algorithm/4011285#4011285) that I asked earlier.

The number of multiplication and addition the following algorithm uses is $2k$ if we assumed the list has $n=2^k$ elements. Since each time we cut the list by half as we multiply $2i$, we would get finally $2k$, where $k=\log(n)$.

**Question**: Could you please tell my if the argument is true I assumed above?

[image]

Comment: Big-O efficiency looks good. The $t$ operations double the runtime but dont affect the algorithm otherwise. If you need integer values for the exact number of multiplications and divisions, note that $\log{n}$ rarely returns an integer value and further note that the while loop will run an extra iteration if $k$ is an integer.

Comment: @DavidDiaz. Thank you. I should bound it with celining/floor function? I don't know why I got downvoted. I tried to put as much details as possible. I am really not sure about the answer and that is why I posted the question.